# Receiving a 'Permission denied' message when checking for regex through shell script

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression

Check the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
check=yes
if [[ $check =~ yes|no ]]; then
    echo yes or no.
else
    echo I did not understood the pattern.
fi
```

Runing in my OSX, everything works as expected. Just throw me the `yes or nor.` message.
But when a run it in the server, an Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, got an error:

```
teste.sh: 3: teste.sh: [[: Permission denied
teste.sh: 3: teste.sh: no: Permission denied
I did not understood the pattern.
```

Already checked the OSX and Ubuntu shell version. OSX ships an older shell version:

```
danilosilva@Bellatrix.local:/tmp/>$SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

While in the Ubuntu:

```
t4h@web129:~$ $SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

To me, the shell informations was not much enlightening.

Is there a different way to check for regex in shell that will run equally through any *nix system and compatible with different shell versions?

Comment: How **exactly** are you running the script?

Comment: Typing in terminal `sh teste.sh`, this way in both OSX and in the Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `bash` script that requires `bash` to be used as the interpreter.

When you run it with `sh`, you're not using `bash`.  Yes, some `sh` is actually `bash` in disguise, but that doesn't matter (it will not behave like "ordinary" `bash` under all circumstances). Treat `sh` and `bash` as mutually exclusive interpreters, as if they were `perl` and `python` (i.e. don't try to mix them).

Run the script with

```
$ bash teste.sh
```

or make it executable an run it directly:

```
$ chmod +x teste.sh
$ ./teste.sh
```

This last way of doing it may be preferable. This lets the script decide, through its `#!`-line, which interpreter should be used.

Comment: Using `bash teste.sh` worked! Thanks!